# updateSliderInput not updating after reactive input change

Tags: r, shiny

I have an input slider and would like the max and value parms updated based on radio button selection.

My testTxt output gets updated correctly with 1/2/3 based on selected radio button but slider does not. I verified the switch statements and they produce the correct result. Is there anything obvious that I might be missing here?

```
wellPanel(
  radioButtons(inputId="radBtns", label="Older than:", choiceNames=c("years","months","days"), choiceValues=c(1:3), selected=2, inline=TRUE),
  sliderInput("timeSld", label=NULL, min=0, max=60, step=1, value=24, width="200px"),
  textOutput("testTxt")
)
```

```
observeEvent(input$radBtns, {
  maxVal <- switch(input$radBtns,opt1=5,opt2=60,opt3=365)
  val <- switch(input$radBtns,opt1={jobData[1,"years"]},opt2={jobData[1,"months"]},opt3={jobData[1,"days"]})
  updateSliderInput(session, "timeSld", value=val, min=0, max=maxVal)
  output$testTxt <- renderText({
    paste0("Selected: ",input$radBtns)
  })
})
```

Comment: The possible values of your `input$radBtns` are not `opt1`, `opt2`, `opt3`. Replace with `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`.

Comment: Thanks Stephane, this worked. My problem was thinking that the input was numeric, therefore the ```opt1```, ```opt2```, etc wouldn't have mattered. If I change the expression in switch statements to ```as.numeric(input$radBtns)``` it works as well without changing to ```"1"```, ```"2"```, etc.